# Continue running a task with terminal disconnected?

Tags: linux, terminal, background-process, command-line-interface, task

Say I'm running a task on a remote (Ubuntu) server which last hours, but I need to disconnect my shell client now. Foolishly, I didn't use `screen` or think of starting the task with `nohup`.

Is there a way to perhaps pause the task, then start it up in the background so it will continue even with my terminal disconnected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not interested in the output, you can use `Ctrl-Z` and then `bg` to run the task in the background, and then `disown` to stop the shell sending it a `SIGHUP` when you disconnect.

Comment: Awesome. I didn't know about `disown`. Weirdly it doesn't have a man page or any help.

Comment: And out of curiosity - if I am interested in the output?

Comment: On RHEL `man disown` opens `BASH_BUILTINS(1)` which has a bit more information.

Comment: If you *are* interested in output, you could start `screen` and use something like [reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr) to reparent it.

Comment: This explains it more: http://www.serverwatch.com/tutorials/article.php/3935306/Detach-Processes-With-Disown-and-Nohup.htm